# Corfu Jews Service chanting: help in identifying Scripture Portion

Tags: torah-service

I recently viewed Lanzmann's "Shoah" documentary and I'm and I'm curious about which passage of the Scriptures the Corfu Jews are chanting in the following segment:

Minute 02.22 Clip FV3409 https://collections.ushmm.org/search/catalog/irn1004584

Comment: Sounds like Hatikvah???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is from ["Yigdal"](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Yigdal?lang=bi)

> This hymn, written by Daniel ben Yehuda, who was a Dayan in Rome about
> 1300, is based on Maimonides’ 13 principles of Judaism.

The tune @Shmuel seems to be the Hatikvah.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like they are singing [Yigdal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yigdal).

Comment: Sorry @Joel K I must have been typing my answer as you typed yours.